# HTTP: Is it acceptable to use the COPY method where the Destination header is not a URI?

Tags: api, http, copy, rfc

## Background

I'm building an API that allows clients to manipulate geospatial objects.  These objects contain a location on the world (in latitude/longitude), and a good bit of metadata.  The actual API is rather large, so I present a simplified version here.

### Current API

Consider an API with two objects, features and attributes.

The feature endpoint is `/api/feature` and looks like:

```
{
    id: 5,
    name: "My super cool feature",
    geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
            -88.043355345726,
            43.293055846667315
        ]
    }
}
```

The attribute endpoint is `/api/attribute`. An attribute looks like:

```
{
    id: 3,
    feature_id: 5,
    name: "attr-name",
    value: "value"
}
```

You can interact with these objects by issuing HTTP requests to their endpoints using different HTTP methods, like you might expect:

- `GET /api/feature/5` reads the feature with id 5.
- `PUT /api/feature/5` updates the feature with id 5.
- `POST /api/feature` creates a new feature.
- `DELETE /api/feature/5` deletes the feature with id 5.

Same goes for attributes.

Attributes are related to features by foreign key (commonly expressed as "features have many attributes").

### The Problem

It would be useful to be able to make a copy of a feature and all its metadata (all the attributes that belong to it).  The use case is more or less, "I just made this feature and gave it a bunch of attributes, now I want the same thing... but over there."  So the only difference between the two features would be their geometries.

### Solution #1: Make the client do it.

My first thought was to just have the client do it.  Create a new feature with the same name at a new location, then iterate through all the attributes on the source feature, issuing `POST` requests to make copies of them on the new feature.  This, however, suffers from a few problems.  First, it isn't atomic.  Should the client's Internet connection flake out during this process, you'd be left with an incomplete copy, which is lame.  Second, it'd probably be slow, especially for features with many attributes.  Anyway, this is a bad idea.

### Solution #2: Add copy functionality to the API.

Doing the copy server-side, in a single API call, would be the better approach.  This leads me to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518#section-8.8 and the `COPY` method.  Being able to do a deep copy of a feature in a single `COPY /api/feature/5` request seems ideal.

## The Question

My issue, here, is the semantics of `COPY` don't quite fit the use I envision for it.  Issuing a `COPY` request on a resource executes a copy of that resource to the destination specified in the `Destination` header.  According to the RFC, `Destination` must be present, and it must be a URI specifying where the copied resource will end up.  In my case, the destination for the copied feature is a geometry, which is decidedly not a URI.

So, my questions are: Would stuffing json for the geometry into the `Destination` header of a `COPY` request be a perversion of the spec?  Is `COPY` even the right thing to use, here?  If not, what alternatives are there?  I just want to be sure I'm implementing this in the most HTTP-kosher way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'll need a way to *make* the Destination a URI then (why is that a problem). If you're using the Destination header field for something else, you're not using COPY per spec. (And, BTW, the current specification is RFC 4918)

Comment: The problem is there's no way to make Destination a meaningful URI.  The URI for a feature is `/api/feature/{id}`, and the id isn't known until the feature is created.  So, `Destination: /api/feature` is the best a client can do, and still needs a place to specify the new feature's geometry (in the body? as a parameter?).

Comment: @jpk How did you solve this? I'm looking at a similar issue.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Sorry for the wait.  It was a long time ago, but I believe I ended up just stuffing the geojson into the Destination header.  At the end of the day I was more concerned with building a logically consistent API than I was offending a spec-writer's sensibilities.  Within the context of that API, it made sense even if it wasn't exactly in line with the spec.  I'd wished there was a spec-sanctioned way to do it, but I didn't find one.